# How to arrange photos in a row rather than a column in a webpage?

Tags: css, wordpress, html-table, html

I am trying to arrange these photos (the ones you see in (http://www.barcaffecitta.it/chi-siamo/) in a row rather than a column. Could someone please explain how this could be done? Also when creating the div for the images, can I just create one div or should I make a div per image?
Also, if you could possibly explain briefly how rows and columns of text or other objects, not only images, can be created with html and css that would be great

Comment: You're asking a lot of different questions there.  You will probably get more responses if you ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question, to get the images to tile horizontally you need to do three things.

1. Set the images to float so they can appear side by side:
2. Make sure your container div is wide enough for the images to fit side by side.
3. Remove the extraneous `<br>` tags after each image.

Your CSS should look like this, more or less.

```
.alignnone {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}

#head-shots {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What is this class (.alignnone) exactly and does it only apply to these images?

Comment: That I don't know.  All these images have that class.  Not sure whether anything else has it.  I just looked at the html in the link you provided through FireBug (which is a great resource if you happen to be using FireFox).  Chrome and Internet Explorer have similar tools.

Comment: You might want to use `.wp-image-122` instead as that class also applies to these images.

Comment: Seems to be working .. I just have to remove the <br> tags but it seems to me that there are no tags.. but visually i can tell there are.. what to do?

Answer (score 0):

for example your image name is image.jpg and it has 100px height and 100px width:

in tag `<head>` put this:

```
<style>
.div_row
{
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.img_column
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat;
  float: right;
}
</style>
```

and in your `<body>` tag put this:

```
<div class="div_row">
  <div class="img_column"></div>
  <div class="img_column"></div>
  <div class="img_column"></div>
  <div class="img_column"></div>
  <div class="img_column"></div>
  <div class="img_column"></div>
</div>
```

you can repeat `<div class="img_column"></div>` as you like.

but i think here is the better suggestion for you!

```
<style>
.div_row
{
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.img_column
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: url('image.jpg') repeat-y;
  float: right;
}
</style>

<div class="div_row">
  <div class="img_column"></div>
</div>
```

this repeats your image for 10! (1000 height / 10 images = 10 slides!)